# Laravel 5 - Project in subdirectory Forbidden - permission denied. And also remove public/ from URL

Tags: laravel-5

I have deployed laravel 5 project in "mydir" and I wants to access using url like http://domain.com/mydir/

When I type above url I get Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /mydir/ on this server.
But when I type http://domain.com/mydir/public it works well. How can I remove that public/ from url of laravel 5 project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the **server.php** in the your Laravel root folder to **index.php** and copy the **.htaccess** file from **/public** directory in your Laravel root folder.
Then little change in .htaccess file like below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: @minc : for fix this issue you set css and js link as like this <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > and <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
and put all your js and css file in public/ folder

Comment: k, I got that and for now i have updated the rule and working for me. 
Ca't we exclude whole assets directory instead of each extension

Comment: @minc :- do you mean this: {{ HTML::script('js/yourfile.js') }}

Comment: I meant instead of {{RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]}} add {{RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(assets|css|images)/$ [NC]}} in htaccess only

Comment: Ya thats true but font and other thing won't get excluded automatically you need to add each extension explicitly !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$

Comment: Has this `server.php` -> `index.php` conversion been documented anywhere? I'm having the same issue as the original poster and would like to have a robust solution to this instead of hacks (which your answer seems like to me).